# How to copy files with Makefile.PL and ExtUtils::MakeMaker?

Tags: perl, makefile, config, ini

I am developing a library and scripts in perl. For distribution I am using `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`, I have some configuration and data files in a directory called `data` in the distribution path, for example the config file is `data/config.ini` and data files like: `data/inv01.stb`. A part of the `Makefile.PL` code follows:

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

my $inifile = 'data/config.ini';
my @data    = <data/*.stb>;    

WriteMakefile(
  NAME => 'Mymodule',
  VERSION_FROM   => 'lib/Mymodule.pm',
  PREREQ_PM  => {
    'Time::HiRes' => 0,
    'Storable'    => 0,
    'File::Path', => 0,
    'File::Copy', => 0,
    'Digest::CRC', => 0,
    'Digest::MD5', => 0,
    'Archive::Tar', => 0,

  },
  EXE_FILES => [ qw(scripts/check_requests.pl  scripts/proc_requests.pl scripts/send_requests.pl) ],
  'clean' => {FILES => clean_files()},
);

# Delete *~ files 
sub clean_files {      
  return join(" ", "*.out", "*~", "data/test/*");
}
```

How can I configure the `Makefile.PL` to copy those files in non standard directory.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Why not use EXE_FILES? After all, they are not going to be checked for runability.